# mysql select from 2 tables as one value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
users

user_id | user_name  | user_avatar
```

and

```
events

event_id | event_name | event_avatar
```

i need a query that will select all avatars in one array, and then, i want to echo them all, as a photo gallery.

can anyone help me please ?

i've tried

```
SELECT e.event_avatar , u.user_avatar as img FROM events e ,users u ORDER BY e.id DESC LIMIT 0, 17"
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query ?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => image1.jpg
            [event_cover] => image.jpg
            [1] => Picture 7_1349112449.png
            [img] => Picture 7_1349112449.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => image.jpg
            [event_main_cover_id] => image.jpg
            [1] => 
            [img] => 
        )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the SQL bit it seems you want a Union:

```
Select
  event_avatar
From
  events
Union All
Select
  user_avatar
From
  users
```